# Numpy arange floating point inconsistency

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point

I have a rather simple numpy task: create an long array with each element incremented by 0.001. Of course, `np.arange` is the answer. I am limiting myself to the default precision (`float64`). A simple check for the result is that every 1000th element of the array should have the same fractional part. I check that by a plot (see blue line in attached figure), and that is not the case.

```
tmin = 212990552.75436273
tmax = 213001474.74473435
tbins = np.arange(tmin, tmax, 0.001)
plt.plot(tbins[::1000] % 1)
```

Hmm, I think... the floating point monster strikes again. My start value is large, but not *that* large that it screws up 64 bit floats. On I hunch, I try the following, which I **think** should mean the same thing:

```
nbins = tmin + np.arange(0, tmax-tmin, 0.001)
plt.plot(nbins[::1000] % 1)
```

Tada! There's a discrepancy right there. The difference monotonically creeps up to 0.14 over the ~10^7 elements in the array. Note that since tmin is x.xxx36273, I expect all numbers to be of the form x.xxx36273. `nbins` has that, `tbins` does not.

```
In [68]: tbins[-1]
Out[68]: 213001474.60374644

In [69]: nbins[-1]
Out[69]: 213001474.74436274
```

A call to `numpy` gurus out there - why is this happening?

[image: Drift seen in the decimal part - blue line is tbins, green line is nbins]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are basically correct; use the second method if you care for the exact decimals of the elements of the array.

In your first attempt, `tbins = np.arange(tmin, tmax, 0.001)`, you are mixing large and small floats in a single computation. The exact value of a given element is computed as the sum of the previous element and `0.001`. This previous value is always huge compared to `0.001`, so this summation will not be very accurate (for best accuracy when doing floating point addition, the two operands should be of the same order of magnitude).

In your second attempt, `nbins = tmin + np.arange(0, tmax-tmin, 0.001)`, the summations in the `np.arange(0, tmax-tmin, 0.001)` part are all very accurate, because the huge number `tmin` is left out, and only added on in the end. This last addition of `tmin` to each element will have poor accuracy, meaning that in the end, each element will have gone through *one* operation with poor accuracy. Compare that to the first attempt, where the value of a given element has the accumulated error of all previous elements. That is, the further on in the array an element is located, the worse off it is (as your plot confirms).

Answer (score 2):

> every 1000th element of the array should have the same fractional part

That would be true for actual numbers but not for floating point values. The floating points values you get do not always match the actual numbers you would expect. For instance you would expect `tbins[1]` to be the number 212990552.75536273, but you get `212990552.75536272` instead, which is the nearest float64 value:

```
In [58]: tbins[0]
Out[58]: 212990552.75436273

In [59]: tbins[1]
Out[59]: 212990552.75536272

In [60]: tbins[0] + 0.001
Out[60]: 212990552.75536272

In [61]: 212990552.75536273
Out[61]: 212990552.75536272
```

Comment: That's fine, my problem is twofold: 1) that the implementation of `np.arange` seems to be such that this difference accumulates over successive additions, and 2) if I use a different method to create the array, still using `float64`, the floating point error is much smaller (at 10^-7 level rather than 10^-2)