# Numpy arange function produces variable of a different length than the variable it depends on

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to make a pyplot graph, but my x and y values are of different length.

I am using numpy's arange function to create the range of x values based on the length of my list of y values.

```
def event_editor(EventDatabase, ConcatenatedEvents, ConcatenatedFits):

    for i in list(EventDatabase):

        # Check for events with absurd blockage current

        if abs(EventDatabase[i]['AllLevelFits'][0]) > 5:
            del EventDatabase[i]
            continue
        event = ConcatenatedEvents[i][0]
        fit = ConcatenatedFits[i]
        x_values = np.arange(0, len(event) / 100, .01)
        x_values2 = np.arange(0, len(fit) / 100, .01)

        fig = plt.figure()
        plt.plot(x_values, event, figure=fig)
        plt.plot(x_values2, fit, figure=fig)
        plt.xlabel('Time (ms)', figure=fig)
        plt.ylabel('Current (I)', figure=fig)
        plt.title('Event #' + str(i), figure=fig)
        plt.show()
```

I'd expect the `x_values` and the `event`/`fit` lists to have the same length, and most of the time they do have the same length. However, when the length of `event`/`fit` is 111, the length of the `x_values` is 112. What causes this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy arange floating point inconsistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40152997/numpy-arange-floating-point-inconsistency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to `float` approximation in Python / NumPy.
The inconsistent behavior is documented also in its official [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html).

A more robust approach is to use: `np.linspace()` e.g.:

```
step = 0.01
np.arange(0, len(event) / 100, step)
np.arange(0, len(fit) / 100, step)
```

becomes, for example:

```
step = 0.01
N = int(max(len(event) / 100 / step, len(fit) / 100 / step))

np.linspace(0, len(event) / 100, N)
np.linspace(0, len(fit) / 100, N)
```

note that with `np.linspace()` you specify the number of points rather than the `step` as last parameter.